# Is Google glass wireless stable and reliable?

Tags: android, network-programming, google-glass, google-gdk

I made a google glass app which receives some data (wireless) from a laptop
and use the data to visualize something. The network connection is simple
UDP or TCP, but I noticed that google glass often miss some data and stop
visualization for a few or several second and continue.

So I'm wondering if Google Glass's wireless network connection is stable
and reliable. Did anyone experience similar or other network problem
with own apps (glassware)?

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify, are you using bluetooth or wi-fi to talk between Google Glass and your laptop?

Comment: Networks in general are not stable or reliable.

Comment: I'm using wifi and a wireless router. So the glass and the laptop connect to the router, and talk to each other within the local network (using local ip address) because wifi direct is not available for google glass. Thank you for your helps.

Comment: it could even be garbage collection causing the delay so it'd be smart to dig deeper into your own code to ensure the problem is in fact originating from the comms or not.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. You cannot expect it to perform as your laptop or phone because instead of full-circuit card that supports 802.11 b/g/n with several antennas, Glass has only one wireless module on its board. That is from a Taiwanese company with module number WM-BN-BM-04 .

[You can see the details about that module **here**](https://www.bluetooth.org/tpg/QLI_viewQDL.cfm?qid=20329) or  [you can even buy it from **Alibaba** for $10](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/WM-BN-BM-04-A-USI-WIFI-Module/1598311438.html) ;) . Thus in your case, you should minimize your data or use/implement an ACKing protocol. But a bigger problem about Glass Wifi is that it only supports WEP -hackable by high school students- and WPA/WPA2. No enterprise. You can have a WIFI connection at home but unfortunately not at university, work etc. So with this in mind, you should probably design only at-home applications with WIFI.